# Undefined Variable: php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error message

> Undefined variable: seller_type (View:
>   /var/www/resources/views/dash/dash.blade.php)

I cant figure out the fix for it, I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something obvious or not.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my dash.blade:

```
  @if(Auth::user()->id)
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <span>Seller Type: </span>
              <select class="seller_type_select" data-type="dash">
                 <option value="call_center" {{$seller_type == 'call_center' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Call Center</option>
                  <option value="dealership" {{$seller_type == 'dealership' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Dealership</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Here is my controller:

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.utf8');
        $this->middleware('acl:view_dash', ['only' => ['index']]);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $role_id = User::UserRoleData()->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first();
        $call_center = Auth::user()->call_center;
        $call_center = ($call_center == null ? '' : $call_center);
        $call_center = !empty($input['call_center']) ? $input['call_center'] : $call_center;
        $month = !empty($input['month']) ? $input['month'] : 'twentyfour';
        $seller_type = Auth::user()->seller_type;
        $seller_type = ($seller_type == null ? '' : $seller_type);
        $seller_type = !empty($input['seller_type']) ? $input['seller_type'] : 'call_center';
        $companies = Company::DistinctCompanies()->orderby('name')->get();
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now -24 months'));

        if($seller_type == '2')
            {
            return $contracts->where('type_id', '=', 'call_center');
            }
            elseif($seller_type == '3')
            {
            return $contracts->where('type_id', '=', 'dealership');
            }

        if ($month == 'twentyfour')
        { 
            if($role_id['id'] == '5' || $role_id['id'] == '6' || $role_id['id'] == '7' || $role_id['id'] == '8')
            {
                if($call_center == '52'){
                    $asi_contracts = array('26', '35', '4', '42', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51');
                    $pending = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $active = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Active')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=","'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $total_reserve = PaymentSchedules::HoldbackTotal(date("Y"))->whereNotNull('actual_payment_date')->leftjoin('contracts', 'contracts.moxy_contract_id', '=', 'payment_schedules.moxy_contract_id')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $outstanding = ContractCancellation::GetYearToDate()->where('affected_date', '<=', date("Y-12-01"))->where('affected_date', '>=', date("Y-01-01"))->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where("sold_date", ">=","'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $cancelled_contracts = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Cancelled')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $late_contracts = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Late')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=","'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $in_default_contracts = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'In Default')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $back_out_contracts = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Back Out')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=","'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $pending_late = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending Late')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                    $pending_cancellation = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Awaiting Cancellation')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where('hold', '=', '0')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your controller index() function is not complete and is not clear what is admin.contracts()

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you haven't defined that variable but are trying to use it in your Blade template.

But notice two things:

1. Your Blade template contains this `@if` statement:

```php
    @if(Auth::user()->id)
```

2. This line in your controller:

```php
$seller_type = Auth::user()->seller_type;
```

Given that the `seller_type` attribute exists on your logged-in user (assuming your controller works, I don't know), you should be able to reference this directly from your Blade template.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to refactor this controller. It is **far** to complex and thus it is hard to see what it actually does. Moreover there are not only DB-Queries in a Controller, they are also raw queries, which you should preferably not use at all in Laravel and surely not for such trivial cases.

I is a miracle that your view does appear **at all** given that you don't actually return a view in you Controller - which is something you absolutely should do. Instead it seems that your view is called in your Middleware - which is something you absolutely should **not** do.

So my advice: Read the Laravel docs and refactor your Constructor according to the examples provided there. This Code is bad and prone to errors.

Comment: agreed that his code is over-complex, but this is not an answer to the question, and is better suited as a comment.